# Java : compile error

Tags: java

I have created a package:

**path** : /home/myid/py_ejb
**File** : XmppMnager.java

```
package xmpp;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
public class XmppManager {
}
```

Compiled with

```
javac -d . -classpath .:smack.jar XmppManager.java
```

**File**: XmppTest.java

```
import xmpp.*;

public class XmppTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String username = "testuser1";
        String password = "testuser1pass";

        XmppManager xmppManager = new XmppManager("myserver", 5222);

..}
```

Compiled with

```
$ javac  -classpath .:smack.jar:./xmpp XmppTest.java 
XmppTest.java:10: cannot access XmppManager
bad class file: RegularFileObject[./xmpp/XmppManager.class]
class file contains wrong class: xmpp.XmppManager
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
        XmppManager xmppManager = new XmppManager("myserver", 5222);
        ^
1 error
```

I tried a lot of way to fix this compilation issue but it just does not go away

Comment: Don't include `./xmpp` in your compilation classpath.

Comment: Directory name and package name have to match.

Comment: I get the same error if I do not include ./xmpp in classpath. Please let me know what should be my directory name , I created using javac -d . option, so it was automatically created

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the source files into a folder named `xmpp` so that the package names match that of the folder

Comment: It worked. That's strange but I did compile using -d . option so why this extra step

Comment: The compiler cannot compile the source files if theyre not in folders that match the package names. IDEs are useful for organising files into their expected folders for you BTW

Answer (score 2):

Package names are directly related to the classpath directory structure. All the classes in the `xmpp` package need to be in a folder named `xmpp`, and this folder must be on the classpath. Similarly, if you had a package called `xmpp.util.io` you would have to put the files in `xmpp/util/io/`.

The usual convention is to make a `src` directory to hold all your source files, and then that can be filled with a directory structure that exactly matches your package structure. A pretty decent tutorial on packages can be found [here](http://tinf2.vub.ac.be/~dvermeir/java/other_doc/JavaPackages.html).

---

Also, it looks like this is probably just a typo in the question, but if your file is actually named `XmppMnager.java` rather than `XmppManager.java`, that won't compile either.